# IOS swift can I get the current visible view from inside the TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a TableView cell and some of the cells have videos on them which is set to to autoplay when I am scrolling and a cell has a video it plays correctly from that I know that the Current index row is working correctly. What I would like to know is how can I get the current visible row from inside the UiTableViewCell ? That way I can stop videos when a user scrolls away . This is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellTVC", for: indexPath) as! MyCellTVC
             let movieURL = URL(string: streamsModel.stream_image_string[indexPath.row])

            cell.videoCapHeight.constant = CGFloat(Float(cell.pic_height!))
            cell.playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL!)
            streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.player = cell.playerView
            streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.view.frame = cell.videoView.bounds
            cell.videoView.addSubview(streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.view)
           controller.addChildViewController(streamsModel.MyAVPlayer)

           streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.player?.play()
   // I would like to get the current visible view row 
   // here so I can do some logic
   return cell

  }
```

I would like to get the row number there since I want to do some logic in there because I have access to UILabels inside the TableView (cell dequeueReusableCell) .

Answer (score 2):

Well, most probably the table view will display more than one cell at time.
To know when a cell is going to be displayed and removed you can implement 2 delegate methods:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
       didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user tableView indexPathForRow method. Implement it in the scrollViewDidScroll and get the indexPath by CGPoint. Change CGPoint by your cell size.

```
extension ViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {

        if let indexPath = tableViewForPoint.indexPathForRow(at: CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y))
        {
            print("Current cell \(indexPath.row)")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the visible cell of the table view, you can use the following code.

```
guard let visibleCell = self.tableView.visibleCells.first else {
   return
}
let view = visibleCell.contentView
```

visibleCell.contentView will give the view of the visible cell.